# integrate play 2 framework with existing Spring MVC app 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc, playframework-2.0

I have an application which is designed using spring 3.1 or 3.2 , i want to integrate play 2 framework into this application, to make is faster and easier for other developers to work with.

It would be really helpful if someone can guide me the steps to do this, or any sample application may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play provides an MVC framework built on Netty. Spring MVC is an MVC framework built on the Servlet API. They are not compatible with each other because they are two completely different ways of doing the same thing, and they can't run alongside each other because they are built on different APIs. Spring MVC doesn't run on Netty (a non blocking, asynchronous http server), and Play doesn't run on the Servlet API (an API for a blocking, synchronous http server).